# Add domain user to local admin group with MDT

Tags: deployment, windows-10, mdt

I have a working task sequence which install Windows 10 pretty well inside a domain and I would like to add this feature : AdminAccounts.

The rule "SkipAdminAccounts=NO" is set, the page appears correctly during the Wizard, but it does nothing : no user has been add to the local admin group.

I haven't see any error or warning in any logs (or maybe I didn't search in the right place).

Maybe I'm missing the right task in my sequence ?
Which task perform this step in the task sequence ?

If someone could help me, I'll appreciate.

Comment: I've had weird things similar to this in the past, what I did to fix it was to make sure that the unattend file had the appropriate XML nodes exposed. You don't have to have any value set in there, just to make sure that the setting is able to be set in the unattended

Comment: It seems you're maybe right. I don't see any parts which can record a login. You can check the unattend file here : https://pastebin.com/JKFvnjDJ